# ios three20 animation on back

Tags: objective-c, ios, three20, ttnavigator

i'm using the three20 lib and in depth ttnavigator:
my question is this:
with this code I change the animation to go in the new navigation:

```
TTURLAction* action;
action = [TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://events"]; 
[action setAnimated:YES];
[action setTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft];
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:action];
```

and the animation is good, but when in the new view I click the back button, the animation is the standard scroll...it's possible mantain the same?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare the URL in the TTURLMap, three20 will do that automatically when you dismiss your view controller:

in your app delegate:

```
TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeNone;
TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;

[map from:@"tt://settings" toViewController:[SettingsController class] transition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft];

[navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://settings"]];
```

and in your settings controller, you can use a custom button, so it won't look as a back button:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];


   TTButton* settingsButton = [TTButton 
                          buttonWithStyle:@"grayToolbarButton:" 
                          title:NSLocalizedString(@"DONE", @"")];
    [settingsButton sizeToFit];

     [settingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissSettings)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                        initWithCustomView:settingsButton] autorelease];
}


 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)dismissSettings {
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```